# Can't access the open /arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

As i'm writing this command after i shift to the kernel. When i compile it, it wasn't showing any list.Is there any other command to open the list ?

```
open /arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl
```

Comment: if the file or directory is not exist so how do i install or create it ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bug

Remove first `/` character from your file path (as it should be [relative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths) path).

### Check file

Now, check that this file exists, using `file` tool:

```
$ file arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl
```

### Print file

If file exists, you can print it using `cat` or `less` commands. E.g.:

```
$ less arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl
```

You can also open this file in editor, e.g. using `vi` command.

### If file absent

This file comes with Linux kernel sources. It was added by [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d181764ccf6207e02abb95fb3052639b947f4833) commit, in kernel 3.3. So you should use kernel version **3.3** or above to have this file.

### How to download kernel with `syscall_32.tbl` file

Download vanilla mainline kernel sources from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/) via [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) (using instructions from [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/)):

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
$ cd linux/
```

Now you should figure out which version to use. It depends on your task (how you are planning to use this kernel further). If it's intended for using on PC Linux distribution, I'd say pick nearest version to your distribution kernel:

```
$ uname -a
```

You can see all versions available by issuing next Git command:

```
$ git tag
```

Now you can switch to version you have chosen (in output from command above). E.g. you can switch to `v3.3` like that:

```
$ git checkout v3.3
```

Switch to version **3.3** or above and your kernel sources will have `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl` file:

```
$ less arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl
```

Comment: i've downloaded the 3.3 kernel but it still not working and showing any list of system calls

Comment: I've added explanation about how to obtain correct kernel sources that contain `syscall_32.tbl` file. No way that **3.3** doesn't have `syscall_32.tbl`, must have been some mistake. But I would recommend you to go with newest version, probably [LTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) one. `v3.18` would be a good choice. Or if you want the lowest LTS version that already has `syscall_32.tbl` -- go with `v3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kernel version `4.9.329` and `syscall_32.tbl` directory was `./arch/×86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`. It also tested on kernel version `6.2.1`.