# No rule to make target `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'

Tags: architecture, linux-kernel

When I tried to enable PPP in the Ubuntu machine the following error occurred after `menuconfig` and trying to make the kernel:

```
$ sudo make
```

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

Ubuntu version linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic was used.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: I tried with this  link but it did not help me. please give me a help to understand this problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951663/cant-access-the-open-arch-x86-syscalls-syscall-32-tbl

Comment: It is exactly because of what you used:
`Ubuntu version linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic was used.`

You want to use a different tree - the one that includes sources. It should be `linux-4.2.0-27`

Comment: I encountered this when trying to run `make` from a directory with a space in the path. When I changed the dir name, all worked.

Answer (score 18):

This could be a syntax error when using `$(PWD)`. Consider changing this:

```
all: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

to this:

```
all: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: +1 but small note: I only had to change $(PWD) to $(shell pwd), not the whole code block (4 lines) into just the 2 lines.

Comment: thank you. this fixed the same problem I had.

Comment: Before attempting this, check if there isn't a `PWD := $(shell pwd)` already defined somewhere in the makefile.

Answer (score 4):

**Short version:**

This is not the complete kernel you are building. Maybe it's just the headers, or something else incomplete. Make sure it's the full kernel sources.

**Long version:**

Not sure on the Ubuntu way of doing it... it seems the normal way doesn't work on ubuntu, eg just for modules (not what you want):

```
apt-get install linux-headers-...
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
make modules_prepare
```

Or for a whole kernel like you want, also doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
apt-get install linux-source-...
cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
make menuconfig
make bindeb-pkg
```

(note that `make bindeb-pkg` is not the pure ubuntu/debian way to build... you use the `make-kpkg` command or something else)

They don't have the build link made for you, and the build fails like yours if you symlink the headers there and copy the .config file. So here's the alternative I have so far, eg. for ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.16):

```
cd /usr/src
apt-get source linux-image-4.4.0
cd linux-4.4.16
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make modules_prepare
```

but the last method is for a kernel that does not match the running one... I don't know if that works for you (It didn't for me, to build an out of tree module, so I also did `make bindeb-pkg` and `dpkg -i ../linux-...` installed the result)

Alternative to using `apt-get source ...`, for the ubuntu sources, you can get the vanilla sources as tgz files from kernel.org or via git.

Comment: `make menuconfig` gives me a kernel configuration menu. What to do?

Comment: @EduardoReis at that point it has generated any config values you needed  but didn't have (much like `make olddefconfig` I think), so you can now edit some things, or just "Exit" and then it'll ask if you wan tto save... say "Yes", and now your file is in ".config", which the build would use.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar message when attempting to build the mt7610u WIFI driver for the ARM Raspberry Pi. Read the README.md and follow the instructions at head of the file. Note it really needs around 900Mb of free space as it downloads the linux kernel source and then builds it.

```
#prepare kernel source code
..if you get this error: no rule, for target „arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl“, 
  needed from „arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd-common.h“

  For new kernel versions 5+ you need to download the latest rpi-sources to fix it:

$ sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/bin/rpi-source
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-source
$ /usr/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update
$ rpi-source

 if you get any question just answer with [y]
```