# Ubuntu 18.10 - problem installing from Makefile - make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl'

Tags: ubuntu

I have the following Makefile:

```
KERNEL_VERSION  := $(shell uname -r)
KERNEL_MODULES  := /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/build

hid-y := hid-magicmouse.o

obj-m += hid-magicmouse.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_MODULES) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_MODULES) M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I run sudo make I receive the following:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-16-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:255: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
```

Is there anything obvious I can do to get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No rule to make target \`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall\_32.tbl', needed by \`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls\_32.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107811/no-rule-to-make-target-arch-x86-entry-syscalls-syscall-32-tbl-needed-by-arch)

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming up against the same..

Change every instance of

```
M=$(PWD)
```

To

```
M=$(shell pwd)
```