# 'No rule to make target 'arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl' when installing wifi modules on raspi

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspbian

I have been trying to install these drivers for ALFA network's AWUS036NEH wifi adapter onto my raspberry pi but I get an error along the way where i run 'sudo make' and i receive the error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.51-v7l+'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl', needed by 'arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/united-common.h'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/Makefile:325:archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.51-v7l+'
make: *** [Makefile:389: LINUX] Error 2
```

I am very new to doing stuff on Linux so I tried troubleshooting to the best of my ability but I couldn't figure it out. Also, if there's more information that's needed to solve this that I didn't provide, I will be sure to provide upon request.

Comment: You probably forgot to **configure** (prepare) the kernel sources before building the module. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107811/no-rule-to-make-target-arch-x86-entry-syscalls-syscall-32-tbl-needed-by-arch).

Comment: I saw that question as well, and it is already written as $(shell pwd) so i dont think its that

Comment: Have you checked [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39291092/3440745) for that question? It tells exactly about not prepared kernel sources.