# make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'. Stop

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, rootkit

### In my project work I have to show demonstration of Rootkit.

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-48-generic
I am using this github repo: https://github.com/nurupo/rootkit
commands I used:-

1. git clone https://github.com/nurupo/rootkit
2. cd rootkit
3. sudo make
   The error I am getting while sudo make is attached below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2wmx.png

Please help

Comment: It seems you forgot to run `make modules_prepare` like desribed in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39291092/3440745) to the question about same error message.