# can't install Edimax PCIe Gigabit Adapter EN-9260TX-E driver on Ubuntu 22.04.3 TLS

Tags: ubuntu, installation, makefile, driver

when I try to make the driver with `make clean modules`  I get the error:

```
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/dvadmin/treiber/src“ wird betreten
rm -rf *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags .tmp_versions Module.symvers Modules.symvers *.order
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/dvadmin/treiber/src“ wird verlassen
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/dvadmin/treiber/src“ wird betreten
make -C /lib/modules/6.2.0-33-generic/build SUBDIRS=/src modules
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic“ wird betreten
make[3]: *** Keine Regel vorhanden, um das Ziel „arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl“, 
  benötigt von „arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h“, zu erstellen.  Schluss.
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:248: archheaders] Fehler 2
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic“ wird verlassen
make[1]: *** [Makefile:42: modules] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/dvadmin/treiber/src“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:32: modules] Fehler 2
```

I've followed the readme to make the driver.

```
<Linux device driver for Realtek Ethernet controllers>

        This is the Linux device driver released for RealTek RTL8168B/8111B, RTL8168C/8111C, RTL8168CP/8111CP, RTL8168D/8111D Gigabit Ether>

<Requirements>

        - Kernel source tree (supported Linux kernel 2.6.x and 2.4.x)
        - For linux kernel 2.4.x, this driver supports 2.4.20 and latter.
        - Compiler/binutils for kernel compilation

<Quick install with proper kernel settings>
        Check whether the built-in driver, r8169.ko (or r8169.o for kernel 2.4.x), is installed.
                # lsmod | grep r8169

        If it is installed, please remove it.
                # rmmod r8169
        note: If the built-in driver cannot removed by rmmod, please edit /etc/modprobe.conf and comment 'alias eth0 r8169'. Then, remmove >

        Unpack the tarball :
                # tar vjxf r8168-8.aaa.bb.tar.bz2

        Change to the directory:
                # cd r8168-8.aaa.bb

        If you are running the target kernel, then you should be able to do :

                # make clean modules    (as root or with sudo)
                # make install
                # depmod -a
                # insmod ./src/r8168.ko (or r8168.o in linux kernel 2.4.x)

        You can check whether the driver is loaded by using following commands.

                # lsmod | grep r8168
                # ifconfig -a
```

I followed a tutorial to install the full kernel:
[https://www.michlfranken.de/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/#:~:text=sudo%20apt%20install%20linux-generic-hwe-20.04%20-y%20Ubuntu%2022.04%3A%20sudo,einem%20sp%C3%A4teren%20Zeitpunkt%20durchf%C3%BChrt%2C%20erh%C3%A4lt%20einen%20neueren%20Kernel](https://www.michlfranken.de/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/#:%7E:text=sudo%20apt%20install%20linux-generic-hwe-20.04%20-y%20Ubuntu%2022.04%3A%20sudo,einem%20sp%C3%A4teren%20Zeitpunkt%20durchf%C3%BChrt%2C%20erh%C3%A4lt%20einen%20neueren%20Kernel).

I tried to config the kernel:
[No rule to make target `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107811/no-rule-to-make-target-arch-x86-entry-syscalls-syscall-32-tbl-needed-by-arch)

I don't know what I did wrong, perhaps because the driver is for the kernel 2.6? Is there a way to make the ethernet adapter working?

I hope someone can help me.

Edit:
the adapter is not listed in the lshw:

```
H/W-Pfad           Gerät           Klasse         Beschreibung
===============================================================
                                    system         Arbeitsplatzrechner
/0                                  bus            D3402-B2
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/11                               memory         16GiB Systemspeicher
/0/11/0                             memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuf
/0/11/1                             memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwRepor
/0/11/2                             memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuf
/0/11/3                             memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwRepor
/0/17                               memory         256KiB L1 Cache
/0/18                               memory         1MiB L2 Cache
/0/19                               memory         8MiB L3 Cache
/0/1a                               processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CP
/0/100                              bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6t
/0/100/14          /dev/fb0         bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/14/0        usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1                       communication  SAMSUNG_Android
/0/100/14/0/7      input6           input          Chicony  HP Wired Desktop 320
/0/100/14/0/8      input9           input          Logitech USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/1        usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                         generic        100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/16                           communication  100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/16.3                         communication  100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/17          scsi1            storage        Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170
/0/100/17/0        /dev/cdrom       disk           BD-RE  BH16NS55
/0/100/17/1        /dev/sda         disk           256GB Samsung SSD 850
/0/100/17/1/1                       volume         511MiB Windows FAT Laufwerk
/0/100/17/1/2      /dev/sda2        volume         237GiB EXT4-Laufwerk
/0/100/17/0.0.0    /dev/sdb         disk           250GB WDC  WDS250G2B0A
/0/100/17/0.0.0/1  /dev/sdb1        volume         99MiB Windows FAT Laufwerk
/0/100/17/0.0.0/2  /dev/sdb2        volume         15MiB reserved partition
/0/100/17/0.0.0/3  /dev/sdb3        volume         232GiB Windows NTFS Laufwerk
/0/100/17/0.0.0/4  /dev/sdb4        volume         524MiB Windows NTFS Laufwerk
/0/100/1b                           bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/1c                           bridge         100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/1c/0        /dev/fb0         display        GF108 [GeForce GT 630]
/0/100/1c/0.1      card1            multimedia     GF108 High Definition Audio C
/0/100/1c/0.1/0    input10          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1c/0.1/1    input11          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1c/0.1/2    input12          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1c/0.1/3    input13          input          HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/1f                           bridge         Q170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Control
/0/100/1f/0                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                         printer        PnP device PNP0400
/0/100/1f/2                         communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/100/1f/3                         communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/100/1f/4                         input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/100/1f/5                         input          PnP device PNP0f03
/0/100/1f/6                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/7                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/8                         system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/100/1f/9                         generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/100/1f/a                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/b                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/c                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/d                         system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/e                         generic        PnP device FXY0815
/0/100/1f.2                         memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3        card0            multimedia     100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/1f.3/0      input14          input          HDA Intel PCH Mic
/0/100/1f.3/1      input15          input          HDA Intel PCH Line
/0/100/1f.3/2      input16          input          HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/0/100/1f.4                         bus            100 Series/C230 Series Chipse
/0/100/1f.6        enp0s31f6        network        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-
/1                                  power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
/2                 input0           input          Sleep Button
/3                 input1           input          Power Button
/4                 input2           input          Power Button
/5                 enx5e86695e5feb  network        Ethernet interface
```

The enp0s31f6 is th on-board adapter.
The last one enx5e86695e5feb is my smartphone.
I can't see the adapter it in the system settings. I also tried another PCIe adapter (the same model).

Comment: please visit https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Why build a driver at all? It's supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: The adapter is not listed in lshw (see my edit above)

Comment: Better use lspci to check for the NIC. If it's not listed there you have a HW/BIOS issue.